# How do I store different documents in production environment?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a "UPLOAD DOCUMENTS" functionality where different customer can upload the required documents and  employer should be able to view all the uploaded documents by the customers. Currently in my local system I can upload the documents and it saves the uploaded file to "inetpub" folder. But in order to provide "upload documents" feature to  production environment what should be the path? Where Can these documents be saved?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So is this an [ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) question?

Answer (score 1):

The files need to be accessible to users for download somehow.  This is tricky however, as it opens you up to security issues if they upload an executable file and then request it.

What I normally do is keep the file information (name, type, etc.) in a database.  Then, I name the file on disk with a consistent naming structure, such as `UPLOAD_ASSET_123456`, with no file extension.  I also keep them out of the web root.

Then, to retrieve to the file from the web end, have a script that accepts an ID, and then the script echos the file contents.